# Como obter apenas os números de uma string em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, regex

Gostaria de saber se há funções que retornem apenas os valores numéricos de uma string, caso não houver, qual a maneira mais simples e eficiente de implementar?

## Exemplo:

```
apenasNumeros("5tr1ng");
```

## Resultado:

> **51**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A maneira mais enxuta que imagino de fazer isso:

```
"5tr1ng0".split("").filter(n => (Number(n) || n == 0)).join("");
```

ou:

```
'5tr1ng0'.replace(/([^\d])+/gim, '');
```

ou:

```
'5tr1ng0'.replace(/\D/gim, '');
```

Comment: Sinceramente eu amei essa sua solução, ela reflete totalmente o JavaScript em sua plena forma de ser simples e eficiente e one liner sempre que possível, fora que não há limitação de precisão decimal :D

Comment: Mas... acabei de achar um porém, e o Zero? ele não funciona porque ele não é considerado Number, e sim um Falsy

Comment: `"00000000aaaaaaaaa1".split(``).filter(n => Number(n) || n == false).join(``)` essa funciona

Comment: Bacana, acrescentei lá para ficar da forma que vc precisa.

Answer (score 30):

```
function apenasNumeros(string) 
{
    var numsStr = string.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    return parseInt(numsStr);
}
```

A maneira mais simples:

1. Usar um regex para eliminar todos os caracteres nao-numeros.
2. Fazer parse para inteiro

**Nota**

Internamente, javascript representa numeros inteiros como virgula flutuante de 64 bits (52bits reservados para a mantissa).
Isto significa que a funcao acima podera fazer parse de inteiros ate +/- 9007199254740992 (2^53).

Parse de numeros acima de 2^53 resulta numa perda de precisao - ou seja, serao adicionados 0's. `parseInt("90071992547409925")` resulta em `90071992547409920`

A alternativa seria simplesmentar retornar o resultado de `replace` (uma string), sem fazer o parse para inteiro.

Comment: +1 bem melhor que a minha resposta, não sei como não pensei nisso!

Comment: teste assim: `apenasNumeros("(48) 3442-7131_1234_4321123")` você terá alguns `0`'s que não existem :p

Comment: @mgibsonbr heh obrigado :) tambem comecei por uma solucao bem mais complicada!

Comment: notei que depois de 20 caracteres começa a aparecer um zero no final, porque? -descobri acho que é por causa do console do firebug kkk

Comment: Um detalhe que talvez o autor da pergunta não saiba: se os números estiverem no início, somente o `parseInt` basta (`parseInt("51foo") === 51`).

Comment: @PauloRoberto boa pergunta. Acho que isto se deve ao facto de os inteiros em javascript se representarem com 64 bits. Isto permite representar um inteiro maximo de 9007199254740992

Comment: é, dava até pra resolver pegando o resultado como string com os numeros e verificar se o `length` é maior que 20, caso não for converter para inteiro, caso for, separar em duas variaveis ou qualquer coisa do tipo, mas sua solução está correta, o prolema é o javascript =p

Comment: Adicionei uma nota relativamente a' perda de precisao. Also, obrigado pela observacao @bfavaretto ;)

Comment: Muito boa a sua explicação relativa a precisão, @dcastro!

Comment: Já que vcs estão falando de trabalhar com números maiores que 52bits, existem libs para dar suporte, por exemplo esta: http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber

Answer (score 8):

Não sei se minha solução é melhor que as demais, mas parece mais simples, pelo menos:

```
$string = "l337 5tr1ng";
$num    = parseInt($string.match(/\d/g).join(''));
```

O `match` procura por números (`\d`), sem parar no primeiro encontrado (flag `g`). Como ele retorna os resultados como um array, você pode dar um `join('')` para juntar tudo renovo e `parseInt` se deseja realizar alguma operação matemática com ele.

Se deseja apenas pegar todos os números num array, basta:

```
$num     = $string.match(/\d/g);
```

Comment: Acredito que este metodo tenha mais operações resultando em uma performance menor. Mas a ideia é boa!

Answer (score 4):

Uma maneira é `parseInt(str.split(/\D+/).join(""), 10)`.

1. A regex `\D+` pega tudo que não é número;
2. Fazendo `split` em torno dessa expressão, dividimos a string em "pedaços" usando essa regex como delimitadora: `["5", "1", ""]`;
3. Fazendo o `join`, unimos ela de novo numa string: `"51"`;
4. Por fim o `parseInt` interpreta a string num número (na base 10; é sempre importante especificar a base, para evitar erros de "zero à esquerda"): `51`.

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/8CdyZ/). Quanto a "mais eficiente", vai depender do seu caso particular (é uma string gigantesca? é um monte de strings pequenas? etc), mas a resposta genérica é "não faz muita diferença na prática"... (i.e. na maior parte dos casos, a diferença de performance entre qualquer solução "razoável" vai ser negligível)

Answer (score 3):

Basta remover todos os caracteres que nao sao numeros utilizando o seguinte regex:

```
string.replace(/\D/g, '') // substitui o que nao for numero por nada
```

### Exemplo:

```js
var str = '(11) 2222-3333_4444_5555$6.777.-@8-!9';
var nums = str.replace(/\D/g, '');
console.log(nums);
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar `isNaN` para checar se a variável não é um número,

```
isNaN(num) // retorna true se num não contém num número válido
```

combinado com a função `filter`, da seguinte maneira

```
"5tr1ng".split('').filter(function(ele){
    return !isNaN(ele);
}).join(''); // retorna "51"
```

Answer (score -1):

forma mais fácil que achei:

```js
    function somenteNumeros(num) {
      var tecla = event.keyCode;
      return (tecla > 47 && tecla < 58)
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="return somenteNumeros(this)"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

let teste = '123 mudar 456';

let retorno = teste.split('').filter(item => Number(item)).join('');

console.log(retorno)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: O problema é que isso exclui os zeros: https://ideone.com/megiUO