# Pegar trecho de uma string entre () em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

Tenho uma string em texto no seguinte formato:

> Tamanho 35 (5 Unidades)

Como eu consigo pegar somente os números que estão dentro dos parênteses, ignorando todo o resto?

Comment: Seja bem vindo Roberto, isto te ajudaria?[Como obter apenas os números de uma string em Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3719/como-obter-apenas-os-n%C3%BAmeros-de-uma-string-em-javascript)

Comment: Coloque na pergunta um [MCVE] mostrando o já fez.

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que não há parênteses aninhados, como por exemplo `"(5 abc (7 xyz))"`, e que dentro dos parênteses só há uma ocorrência do número (não tem casos como `"(123 abc 456 xyz 789)"`), uma forma de fazer seria:

```js
let s = 'Tamanho 35 (5 Unidades), abc 123 (456 xyz) etc 999';
for (const match of s.matchAll(/\([^)\d]*(\d+)[^)\d]*\)/g))
    console.log (match[1]);
```

A ideia da regex é pegar algo entre parênteses, indicado por `\(` e `\)` - parênteses [possuem significado especial em regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) e preciso escapá-los com `\` para que sejam interpretados como os próprios caracteres `(` e `)`.

Em seguida temos `[^)\d]*`: zero ou mais caracteres que não sejam `)` e nem `\d` (um dígito de 0 a 9).

Depois temos `\d+`, que indica um ou mais dígitos, e depois zero ou mais caracteres que não sejam o parênteses bem dígitos.

O trecho correspondente aos dígitos eu coloquei entre parênteses para formar um grupo de captura, assim consigo pegar seu conteúdo depois com `match[1]` (como é o primeiro par de parênteses, então é o grupo 1).

---

Se tiver casos como `"(123 abc 456 xyz 789)"` (mais de um número entre os parênteses), então uma solução seria primeiro pegar o conteúdo entre parênteses e depois pegar os números de dentro dele:

```js
let s = 'Tamanho 35 (5 Unidades), abc 123 (123 abc 456 xyz 789) etc 999';
for (const conteudoParenteses of s.matchAll(/\(([^)]+)\)/g)) {
    for (const numero of conteudoParenteses[1].match(/\d+/g))
        console.log(numero);
}
```

Agora eu uso apenas `[^)]+` (um ou mais caracteres que não sejam `)`) para pegar o conteúdo dos parênteses, e em seguida uso `\d+` (um ou mais dígitos) para pegar todos os números que tiver dentro dele.

Answer (score -3):

Salve. Você pode usar a função Split, como listada [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Assim, vc pode usar o Split para salvar o texto após o ' ( ' e em seguida, repetir o processo, dando um Split no caractere Espaço.

Você pode usar o conceito de desestruturação para deixar o código mais limpo.

Exemplo:

```
resultado = stringExemplo.split("(");
```

Isso irá retornar um Array contendo ["Tamanho 35 ", "5 Unidades)"]

Como só a segunda parte lhe interessa, pode fazer assim:

```
[,resultado] = stringExemplo.split("(");
```

Com isso você teria apenas a segunda parte ["5 Unidades)"]

Acho que deu para entender. Tem mais um link interessante [aqui](https://www.devmedia.com.br/javascript-split-dividindo-separando-strings/39254).